# サーバー内の特定のプログラムが外部にアクセスするURLを書き換えたい

Tags: linux

サーバー（CentOS7）上に複数のスクリプトが複数の言語で記述されています．
これら全てのスクリプトが参照するURLを個別に書き換えることなく，
ファイアウォールのように，それらのスクリプトについてアクセスを監視し，
それらのスクリプトがサーバーの外（e.g. http://hoge1.hoge）を参照しようとした場合に，
これを別のURL（e.g. http://hoge2.hoge）に変更してアクセスさせる方法がないか調べています．
このようなことは可能でしょうか？
検索のためのキーワードだけでも与えていただければ，嬉しいです．

Comment: URL表示は書き換えられないので要件に合わないかもしれませんが・・・。ドメインを変更したいのであれば、アクセス先サーバを変える /etc/hosts を使ってみるのはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

アクセスを書き換えるような HTTP プロキシを用意し、これを経由させる事になると思います。
HTTP 通信を行なう多くのプログラムが、環境変数 `HTTP_PROXY` や `http_proxy` を参照してこれに従いますので、通常はこれを設定します。

こういった設定を尊重しないプログラムに対応するには「透過プロキシ」と呼ばれる仕組みを用います。
透過プロキシを実現するには OS レベルでの対応が必要で、Linux であれば `iptables` などで設定します。
（「特定のプログラムだけ」という点が難しいかも知れないですね。対象のプログラムはコンテナに入れておく、とかでしょうか。）